# .htaccess Redirect Issue , struggling with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am struggling with an url/parameter issue.

The main index.php page of my website was previously used for e.g.

`www.domain.com/index.php?site=3&word=21` and

`www.domain.com/index.php?site=3`

But now I have changed those things, but in Google the URLs are still listed. So what I need is to redirect all the type of pages above to the `main page/domain www.domain.com`.

I believe .htaccess redirect is the right thing to use then, is that correct?

What type of code do I need to redirect those to main domain. Just the url's with parameters after `index.php?` etc. not other directories e.g. `www.domain.com/sunshine/`

Would be great if someone could help me with this. I believe it is actually a quick fix, but I have failed to get the code correct.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search on SO? There are plenty of examples for you to start with.

Comment: Yes, I searched and tried several examples. But did not find something that did just want I am looking for. You might have an example of similar?

Comment: I have spent days working on this? I have tried e.g. RewriteRule ^index.php http://www.domain.com/? [L,R=301]

Comment: Please edit your post and add sample input URLs and expected rewritten or redirected URLs. If I understand your question correctly then you did not search very well: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+index.php+from+urls

Comment: How `www.domain.com` is being redirected to `www.domain.com/index.php...`. Include the relevant set of rules in your question to make sure a loop won't be generated with the redirection in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to an .htaccess in your site root:

`RedirectMatch permanent ^/index.php* http://www.domain.com/`

But, be careful if your new index page is also named index.php because you might run into a redirect loop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The new index page is also named index.php . So that will then cause a problem? Is there anyway to work around it ?

Comment: In that case, do you actually need a redirect? Is your new index.php doing something with the extra URL parameters (?site=3, etc.)? If not, then the Google links should just direct people to the new homepage.

Comment: the problem is that the main page displays as it should but with e.g. the www.domain.com/index.php?site=3&word=21 as url. But I need the link to say www.domain.com instead for the main page, due to search engine optimizing.  Is there any chance of doing that?